# If $\Phi_e^{-1}(C \cap \bar e)$ is compact, then $C \cap \bar e$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, cw-complexes

Could someone explain why what's in the red box is true?  How does the compactness of $\Phi_e^{-1}(C \cap \bar e)$ imply the compactness of $C \cap \bar e$?

[image]

Comment: apply $\varphi$ to both sides

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Phi_e$ is surjective onto $\overline{e}$, $\Phi_e(\Phi_e^{-1}(C\cap \overline{e}))=C\cap\overline{e}$.  Thus $C\cap \overline{e}$ is the continuous image of a compact set and hence compact.